# "Been quite a trip, it has" - Correct or Incorrect?

Tags: present-perfect, word-order

I came across a phrase which was used in a random American TV series. The phrase looks like this:

> **Been** quite a trip, **it has**

I highly doubt it's grammatically incorrect. I also have tried to find similar topics related to this one, unfortunately I haven't gotten any answers yet. Is it a dialect type of phrase? I'd like to hear your opinions.

Comment: It's unusual and nonstandard, but technically grammatical—although I would add a comma after *trip*. It's an inverted version of *It has been quite a trip*. I could say, "Sounds like Yoda, it does." It's a construction that should not normally be used. In fact, I'd say it would be *better* if rewritten as *quite a trip, it has been*. But it's difficult to talk about what should fall where when it's already such an odd form.

Comment: By adding a comma, it's more explainable. I'll just edit the main post and wait for other thoughts.

Comment: @JasonBassford -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> "Been quite a trip, it has"

along with

> "quite a trip it has been"

are both reversals of the usual grammatical format of English. It essentially flips the verb and descriptive phrases of the sentence. **"Quite a trip it has been"** is slightly more correct because it keeps the description together (**"quite a trip"**) and the subject-verb together (**"it has been"**); these can be arranged in either order as long as the internal pieces stay together and in order. For example, "trip quite a, been it has" would not make any sense, as the order within the two pieces has been scrambled.

"Been quite a trip, it has" works more along the lines of "[it has] been quite a trip, it has", where the brackets are implied meaning and the additional "it has" acts as a repetitive confirmation.

While these constructions all work and are intelligible, including the verb at the end (the "it has") is not common and will give a formal, archaic, or stilted feeling to the sentence. (This is why Yoda comes across as more thoughtful and wise - he constructs his sentences in the less-intuitive and common pattern.)